# How to unit-test a class which has methods using database connection?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit5, spring-boot-test

I am trying to run tests on a `controller` class and it has atleast a method which internally uses a `DAO` to retrieve information from the `DB (MySQL)`.

The problem I have is that the dao method is giving null and I end up with `NullPointerException` error.

**How do I tests a class which has methods that internally use a database connection?**
Haven't been able to find any useful post/answer.

Project structure:

```
src
    main
        java
            [package]
                RegisterController.java
                Config.java // configuration class
    test
        java
            [package]
                RegisterControllerTest.java
```

**RegisterController.java**

```
package com.webapp.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import com.webapp.Config;
import com.webapp.dao.AccountDao;

@Controller
public class RegisterController {

    @Autowired
    AccountDao accDao;


    public String validateUsername(String uname){
        List<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();

        // ... unrelated code 

        // NullPointerException thrown here
        if(accDao.getAccountByUsername(uname) != null)
            errors.add("err#taken");

        return errors.toString();
    }
}
```

**RegisterControllerTest.java**

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import com.webapp.controller.RegisterController;
import com.webapp.Config;

@SpringBootTest
public class RegisterControllerTest {

    @Mock
    private Config config;

    private RegisterController rc;

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        config = Mockito.mock(Config.class);
        rc = new RegisterController();
    }


    @Test
    public void testValidateUsername() {
        assertEquals("[]", rc.validateUsername("Username123")); // N.P.E

    }
}
```

**Config.java**
package com.webapp;

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

import com.webapp.dao.AccountDao;
import com.webapp.dao.AccountDaoImpl;
import com.webapp.dao.Dao;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.webapp.controller", "com.webapp.dao", "com.webapp.test" })
public class Config {

    private static class Database {
        private static String host = "127.0.0.1";
        private static String user = "root";
        private static String pass = "root";
        private static String dbname = "memedb";
        private static int port = 3306;

        public static String getUrl() {
            return "jdbc:mysql://"+host+":"+port+"/"+dbname+"?serverTimezone=Europe/Stockholm";
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public DriverManagerDataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        ds.setUrl(Database.getUrl());
        ds.setUsername(Database.user);
        ds.setPassword(Database.pass);
        return ds;
    }


    @Bean
    public AccountDao getAccDao() {
        return new AccountDaoImpl(getDataSource());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of mocking `config`, mock the `Dao`. You are getting NPE, because the mocked config is not setting `@Autowired accDao`... so your `accDao == null`:

```java
@Controller
public class RegisterController {

    AccountDao accDao;

    public RegisterController(AccountDao accDao) {
      this.accDao = accDao;
    }

    ...
}
```

```java
@BeforeEach
public void init() {
  accDaoMock = Mockito.mock(AccountDao.class);
  rc = new RegisterController(accDaoMock);
}

@Test
public void testValidateUsername() {
  when(accDaoMock.getAccountByUsername("Username123")).thenReturn(null);
  assertEquals("[]", rc.validateUsername("Username123"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you configuring the connection DB programmatically? I advise you configure the connection DB with autoconfiguration of Spring Boot.

The DAO object have to mock in an unit test.
[Here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing) is a good article about the Junit test for a Spring Boot App.